# TypeError: 'price' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django-models

I wrote this class in my text editor called Blog. Here it is:

```
# Create your models here.
class Blog(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price       = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)
    summary     = models.TextField()
#sample app
```

I  tried to create an object for class Blog via python shell in terminal and I passed these arguments:
`Blog.objects.create(title='Discount Day', price=49.99, summary='discounts')`

Every time I press enter I keep getting error for price as follows: TypeError: 'price' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Despite having stated that price is a DecimalField

I didn't make any changes to models.py but rather just added another object

Comment: Have you done your migrations?

Comment: Whenever you make any changes to models.py, you have to migrate otherwise it won't work.

Comment: the model is already updated, so no need. Plus, it didn't detect anyway